# Javascript Values for letters

Tags: cordova, variables, switch-statement

I am developing an app in Phonegap.. My app is based on numerology calculation, In my app there is a portion where I need to calculate the value of letters. For example my name 'Aron' .. I need to calculate the values, I am using switch case statement for that but it is not working.. can anyone pls help me to find out the error..I am giving my code below.

//curage is current age
//fna is firstname

```
var bbbb;


 for(var i=0; i<curage; i++) 
  {
    bbbb+=lettervalue(fna.charAt(i));

  }

function lettervalue(var g)
{

var cccc;
switch(g)
        {
           case a: cccc="1";           
           break;           
           case b: cccc="2";
           break;
           case c: cccc="3";
           break;
           case d: cccc="4";
           break;
           case e: cccc="5"; 
            break;     
           case f: cccc="6"; 
            break;         
            //till z
        }

return cccc;
}




document.getElementById("hbt").value=cccc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jocheved you switch case statment should be like this..
inside argument dont use `var`

```
function lettervalue(g)
{
switch(g)
        {
           case "a": return 1;                    
           case "b": return 2;          
           case "c": return 3;           
           case "d": return 4;           
           case "e": return 5;                  
           case "f": return 6;                        
           default : return 0; 

        }

}
```

and change the last line like this..instead of 'cccc' change to 'bbbb'

```
document.getElementById("hbt").value=bbbb;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the cases with strings, your letters must be between "

```
case "a": cccc="1";           
       break;
```

In javascript you dont declare a variable as an argument function:

```
function name(argument){   <--- not (var argument)
     code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first in terms of function signature, you can't use `var` inside the arguments.

```
function lettervalue(var g)
```

Need to be

```
function lettervalue(g)
```

Then inside your `switch` case, you need to have `String`

```
  case "a": 
           cccc="1";           
           break;
```

Comment: let me check mohammed