# Javascript Variable concatenate instead of adding

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova, concatenation

value of variables are need to be added in for loop .. but instead of adding it is concatenationg ..I need to add together...

I will give my code pls help..

```
//curage is current age
//fna is firstname

var bbbb=0;
while(bbbb < curage ) 
{
  for(var i=0; i<fna.length; i++) 
  {   
    bbbb += lettervalue(fna.charAt(i));
  }
}


function lettervalue(g)
{
switch(g)
        {
           case "a": return "1";                    
           case "b": return "2";          
           case "c": return "3";           
           case "d": return "4";           
           case "e": return "5";                  
           case "f": return "6";  
           case "g": return "7";                    
           case "h": return "8";          
           case "i": return "9";           
           case "j": return "1";           
           case "k": return "2";                  
           case "l": return "3"; 
           case "m": return "4";           
           case "n": return "5";                  
           case "o": return "6";  
           case "p": return "7";                    
           case "q": return "8";          
           case "r": return "9";           
           case "s": return "1";           
           case "t": return "2";                  
           case "u": return "3";
           case "v": return "4";           
           case "w": return "5";                  
           case "x": return "6";  
           case "y": return "7";                    
           case "z": return "8";          
           default : return "0" 

        }
}
```

I am getting result like 1234 but I need to get sum of this like 1+2+3+4 = 10.

Comment: Try to change your return values to numbers (without the quotes).

Comment: yes... can you post it as an answer.. I will accept it

Comment: are you going to ask every time you try a new thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671625/javascript-values-for-letters why don't you try to learn javascript before trying to create an app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, return numbers instead of string. Otherwise javascript builds up a string with the + operator thinking you wanted to concatenate chars instead of adding numbers.

```
case "a": return 1;                    
case "b": return 2;          
case "c": return 3;           
case "d": return 4;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the quotation marks around the numbers in your `lettervalue` function, it makes Javascript treat them as strings instead of numbers.

Eg:

```
  case "d": return 4;
```

instead of

```
  case "d": return "4";
```

Answer (score 2):

return integer i.e. 1,2 without quotes should solve your problem.

Else try

```
bbbb += parseInt(lettervalue(fna.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
case "a": return "1";
```

change it to..

```
case "a": return 1;
```